# How to make long calls to a COM object while the interface shows a progress bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, com

I'm making a program in C# (WPF) that calls functions in a COM object. Some of these functions take some time, like 5 to 10 seconds to return. If these calls are made by the UI thread, the interface becomes unresponsive, so that I would like to make the calls from a secondary thread and use the UI's to display a dialog window containing an indeterminate progress bar.

Well, to make the calls from a secondary thread, I must initialize the COM object in it. Trouble is: after the function returns, the secondary thread is lost. When I need to make another call, I have to create a new (third) thread, to which the COM object doesn't belong, and that throws me an exception. I can't instantiate a new COM object because I depend on the state the previous calls led to.

The possible solutions I see:

- Initialize the COM object and make the calls from the UI thread, and use the secondary one to display the progress bar window. Doesn't seem to be pretty correct though;
- Initialize the COM object in the secondary thread and leave it idle, waiting for the UI thread to invoke. I've been struggling to do this one, because I couldn't figure out so far how to put the secondary thread in the idle state and how to invoke the the functions through the UI thread (can't create a dispatcher).
- Any other idea?

Thank you guys in advance!

Code sample:

```
private ARK.ICore ark;  // COM object
private ProgressWindow progressWindow = new ProgressWindow();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

// Example of use of the COM object (assume this will be used first)
private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ark = new ARK.Core2();  // COM object initialization
        ark.OpenDevice(0);
        progressWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(progressWindow.Close);
        // Here the thread is lost, so I can't call the functions of ark in its own thread
    });

    thread.Start();
    progressWindow.ShowDialog();
}

// Another example of use of the COM object (assume this will be used later)
private void InitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ark.Init(ARK.EarConstants.fLeft, null); // ark object initialized in another thread, exception thrown
        progressWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(progressWindow.Close);
    });

    thread.Start();
    progressWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you create a dispatcher on the secondary thread so that it stays alive? Is it because of the apartment state that the COM object must work in? If that is the case, can't you encapsulate a message loop in a custom class?

Comment: have you stepped thru the code ..? also when creating an Instance of the ComObject are you using the correct method call to Dispose of the Initial ComObject showing code is always the best approach when posting questions such as yours.. thanks

Comment: @feO2x: I tried creating the secondary thread and calling the method Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread), but it always returns null. I've also read something about pumping a message loop, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Yes, I did step thru the code and found out what the problem is, now I'm looking for the solution. About the COM object instance, when I say that I can't instantiate a new object, in fact I can, but I'm not interested. The functions I call in the object modify its internal state, so that I must keep it, instead of disposing and creating a new instance.

Comment: can you at least show what you are doing so we can visually see where you may be having this disconnect..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: There it is. The whole code is too big to post here, so I simplified, to show you the idea. I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the solution is:

> Initialize the COM object in the secondary thread and leave it idle, waiting for the UI thread to invoke.

You indeed need to create your thread the way you do, and instantiate the COM object in that thread. But then you should not let the thread die, you should have it wait for commands from the GUI thread and process them. Assuming you use .NET 4.0 or later, this should get you started:

```
// make this a field
BlockingCollection<Action<ARK.Core2>> queue = 
    new BlockingCollection<Action<ARK.Core2>>();

// initialization code, execute e.g. when application starts or main window is loaded
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var ark = new ARK.Core2();  // COM object initialization

    foreach (var action in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        action(ark);
    }

    // cleanup ark here
});

thread.Start();
```

Then, to do something with the COM object from the UI thread, do

```
queue.Add(ark => ark.SomeMethod());
```

If you need to update your UI, make sure to call the dispatcher, for example:

```
queue.Add(ark =>
{
    ark.SomeMethod();
    progressWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(progressWindow.Close);
});
```

When you are finished, and want to free the COM object and close the thread, call

```
queue.CompleteAdding();
```

For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

Comment: Got it! The performance was not so good, but it worked anyway. I'll try to optimize my code and see what I get. Thank you!

Comment: @Milak What do you mean with "the performance wasn't good"? You do this because the call to the COM method could take 5 to 10 seconds to return. There is no way this would add a significant overhead on top of that. At least, I would be extremely surprised if it did.

Comment: I mean, before I implemented your solution, I tested the functions by calling them from the UI interface and waiting it to respond. Now that the function is called by another thread, the time it takes is significantly longer. Maybe I'm missing something, I'm working on it.

Comment: There is no doubt that this cross-thread marshalling is zillions times slower than a direct call. It might take milliseconds to do the thing that works, where it would only take nanoseconds to do the thing that doesn't. It also takes time to display a progress bar, especially when it sits in its own window, and close that down again. Not to mention again the five to ten seconds the COM component takes. You know what's fastest? Doing nothing, that takes no time at all.

Comment: Sure, it must be the cross-thread marshalling. I'm quite convinced that showing the progress bar and closing it is pretty fast. I'm so frustrated, but the best I could do is to call the COM object in the UI thread, and create another one to show the progress bar.

Comment: @Milak Just curious, how slow is this, and how do you know? You are not measuring in the debugger, are you?

Comment: No, I'm not measuring in the debugger, I know it just because I have to wait for the time it takes. One of the functions is quite fast than the others, such that I don't even need the progress bar window. When I call that function on the UI thread, it takes like one or two seconds. When using the BlockingCollection queue, it takes like 5 to 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use task which can return object to UI thread

```
 private void MethodThatWillCallComObject()
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //this will call in background thread
                return this.MethodThatTakesTimeToReturn();
            }).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                //t.Result is the return value and MessageBox will show in ui thread
                MessageBox.Show(t.Result);
            }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

        private string MethodThatTakesTimeToReturn()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return "end of 5 seconds";
        }
```

Comment: -1 Although I think what you are trying to say it right...What you are ACTUALLY saying isn't.

Comment: I normally put the .net 4.5.1 version up before the OP notes they use .net 4.0, simply because its so much more succinct.